# Function Pointers typecasting

Tags: c

I was trying a code as below.

```
int TestMethod(int a, int b)
{
    printf("In TestMethod %d, %d \r\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}


int main(void)
{

    void (*ap_cb_function)() = (void(*)())TestMethod;
    ap_cb_function();

    return 0;
}
```

It works out well with gcc compiler. This prints the output with random values of a and b. How does this work? I was expecting an error at line :

```
void (*ap_cb_function)() = (void(*)())TestMethod;
```

Comment: "It works out well with gcc compiler " The compiler isn't *running* your program; its simply generating code for what you explicitly told it to do, no matter how bad that may be. You could cast it to an `int* p` and write `*p = 1;` if you want, and the behavior would be just as **undefined**.

Comment: I've tried this on [ideone](http://ideone.com/avSl8H) and it also runs successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function arguments are passed either in registers or on stack, depending on the ABI of your platform. If you don't specify the arguments, some random values (in the registers or on stack) would still be there from the view of the called function....

Comment: also, these arguments would be mistakenly popped out upon return.